# Weighted graph from a matrix (list-of-lists)

Tags: python, python-2.x

I created this code while solving [the Euler Project problem 83](https://projecteuler.net/problem=83).

> In the 5 by 5 matrix below, the minimal path sum from the top left to
>   the bottom right, by moving left, right, up, and down, is indicated in
>   bold red and is equal to 2297.

[image: Data]

> Find the minimal path sum, in matrix.txt (right click and "Save
>   Link/Target As..."), a 31K text file containing a 80 by 80 matrix,
>   from the top left to the bottom right by moving left, right, up, and
>   down.

I have a matrix with weights stored as a list-of-lists. The task is to traverse the matrix from the top-left element to the bottom right element. At every point, I can go up, down, left or right. The problem is to find the path with the minimal summed weights.

To answer this, I converted the matrix to a graph (`Make_Graph`), represented as a dictionary in Python. The key in the dictionary is the string `row_index, column_index` (`Name_Name`). My next step in solving the Euler problem (not shown here) is to use [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path.

I'm an amateur Python enthusiast, not a professional programmer. I have the feeling that `Make_Graph` can be made more Pythonic, but I don't know how. It looks a bit messy to me.

```
def node_name(row_index, col_index):
    return str(row_index)+","+str(col_index)

def make_graph(matrix):
    graph={}
    for rowindex,row in enumerate(matrix):
        for colindex,value in enumerate(row):
            graph[node_name(rowindex,colindex)]={}
            # Up
            if rowindex>0: graph[node_name(rowindex,colindex)][node_name(rowindex-1,colindex)]=matrix[rowindex-1][colindex]
            # Down
            if rowindex<len(matrix)-1: graph[node_name(rowindex,colindex)][node_name(rowindex+1,colindex)]=matrix[rowindex+1][colindex]
            # Left
            if colindex>0: graph[node_name(rowindex,colindex)][node_name(rowindex,colindex-1)]=matrix[rowindex][colindex-1]
            # Right
            if colindex<len(row)-1: graph[node_name(rowindex,colindex)][node_name(rowindex,colindex+1)]=matrix[rowindex][colindex+1]
    return graph

print make_graph([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, both `node_name` and `make_graph` can be a bit smaller, yes.

```
def node_name(row_index, col_index):
    return "{},{}".format(row_index, col_index)
```

`format` will do the string conversion automatically, no need to call `str`.

I'd also give everything a bit more space to make it more readable.

```
def make_graph(matrix):
    graph = {}

    width, height = len(matrix[0]), len(matrix)

    columns = range(width)
    for rowindex in range(height):
        for colindex in columns:
            graph[node_name(rowindex, colindex)] = x = {}

            # Up
            if rowindex > 0:
                x[node_name(rowindex - 1, colindex)] = matrix[rowindex - 1][colindex]
            # Down
            if rowindex < height - 1:
                x[node_name(rowindex + 1, colindex)] = matrix[rowindex + 1][colindex]
            # Left
            if colindex > 0:
                x[node_name(rowindex, colindex - 1)] = matrix[rowindex][colindex - 1]
            # Right
            if colindex < width - 1:
                x[node_name(rowindex, colindex + 1)] = matrix[rowindex][colindex + 1]

    return graph
```

Except caching more things this would look okay to me.  Relying a
rectangular matrix seems obvious to me, so `width` and `height` can be
precomputed.  Using `range` also makes it more clear that you really
want the coordinates, not the row or column values.

In the interest of verbosity I'd also just `i` and `j` for indexes, but
that's your choice obviously.

Also, you know that `{(1, 1): 1}` works, right?  Because there doesn't
seem to be a pressing reason to use `node_name` at all.  In contrast to
a `list` a `tuple` is immutable and can be used as a dictionary key, see
also [this wiki page for a more thorough discussion on that](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys).

Comment: Maybe explain why `(1, 1)` can be a key even though `[1, 1]` can't.